# Batch Script to generate Landscape files with cPDF?

Tags: batch-file, pdf, cmd, command-line, forfiles

See if anyone can help me.
For example:

I have a .pdf document with 4 pages.

With the command below I can make this .pdf document have two pages, that is, two pages on the same sheet in "landscape" format

`cpdf -twoup-stack in.pdf -o out.pdf`

But I need to make it work on multiple files in the same folder. I tried the command below and it didn't work. If anyone has a solution I would appreciate it, I'm a beginner.

This prints only one file from the folder.

`cpdf -twoup-stack path\*.pdf -o out.pdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your using the windows version thus from cmd prompt to process all multi-page files in current folder you could use the simpler

`forfiles /m *.pdf /c "cmd /c cpdf -twoup-stack in.pdf -o out-@file"`

so in1.pdf becomes out-in1.pdf

similar is

`for  %f in (*.pdf) do cpdf -twoup-stack in.pdf -o "out-%f"`

It is more convenient to use a batch.cmd file with a different `for` structure, with some variables to allow drag and drop or specify a default folder etc.

so if the following `2up.cmd` is placed in a work folder with multiple pdfs it will on entering `2up` at a cmd prompt or `a simple double click` on that cmd file then process all the pdf files in that working folder.

Note a batch file needs %% where a cmd line would just need one but the single %~ inside the brackets is correct ! also define the folder for cpdf to ensure it is the only cpdf command accessed and generally "double quote" to avoid problems with spaces.

```
@echo off
REM ensure we only run in this file.cmd dir not any system dir
cd /d "%~dp0"

for %%F in ("%~dp0*.pdf") do "c:\path to\cpdf.exe" -twoup-stack "%%F" -o "%%~dpnF-out.pdf"
```

The result will be a rotated imposition compared to source pages so the next step is usually add a second command at the end to rotate those-out.PDFs.

`for %%F in ("%~dp0*-out.pdf") do "c:\path to\cpdf.exe" -rotate 90 "%%F" -o "%%~dpnF-2up.pdf"`

If you are going to run twice for 4-up it becomes more desirable to delete work files so in that case consider if a 3rd) `del "%~dp0*-out.pdf"` is also required before 4) ...*-2up.pdf ...-out.pdf and 5) -out.pdf to -4up.pdf

4-up is generally 2-up twice so I gave hints above about add extra lines at the end, in comments you tried and found only 3 steps as for loops needed for your desired use :-

This may not be the most efficient way (but is now one single `for` loop, so retains the logic) it can be used as a template for different executables and different function sequences.
4-up.cmd

```
@echo off
REM we will be changing % values % during ! runtime !
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM ensure we only run in this file.cmd dir not any system dir
cd /d "%~dp0"

REM we can set a work directory here from command line or drag and drop and use it later
REM but that's a further customization based on user choices

REM set mode to -twoup or -twoup-stack (see cpdf manual)
set "mode=-twoup-stack"

REM set cpdf command location
set "theExe=C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop\SandBox\apps\PDF\cpdf\New folder\cpdf.exe"

REM using current folder and restricting file set to *.pdf

for %%F in ("%~dp0*.pdf") do (
  set "name=%%~nF"
      echo processing !name!

  "%theExe%" %mode% "!name!.pdf" -o "%temp%\!name!-tmp1.pdf" 2>nul
      dir /b "%temp%\!name!-tmp1.pdf"

  "%theExe%" %mode% "%temp%\!name!-tmp1.pdf" -o "%temp%\!name!-tmp2.pdf" 2>nul
      dir /b "%temp%\!name!-tmp2.pdf"

  "%theExe%"  -rotate 180 "%temp%\!name!-tmp2.pdf" -o "%~dp0!name!-4up.pdf" 2>nul

  REM lets remove the temporary files to ensure no mix-up on runs
  del "%temp%\!name!-tmp?.pdf"
      echo deleted tmp files

  echo "%~dp0!name!-4up.pdf" done
)
pause
```

You can delete those `dir` lines echoing progress, if you want a more silent run and then the pause is not required if double click running the cmd file.

***To save your -outputs in a different folder the simplest will be to change end of last

`-o "%~dp0!name!-4up.pdf"`

to point to a different folder but keep the Filename so

`-o "c:\folder name\!name!.pdf"`***

To adapt to a remote folder or for drag and drop is beyond this question so try `FOR /?` to see many other options including adapting to work with sub directories. For a single file drag and drop variant modify similar to https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/blob/master/AppNotes/SumatraPDF/Addins/N-Up-PDF/2-Up-PDF.cmd

Comment: @k-j Your code was interesting to me, the cmd script you prepared in the answer worked.

If it's not too bothersome or pretentious of me and you're willing to teach me. I couldn't get it to work with forfiles.
And your script does what I need, but it saves the new files in the same folder, how do I get the generated files saved in another folder than the source one.

I saw that you mentioned that the same procedure is possible for 4up, how do I do it. 4 pages of the same sheet?

I use Windows system.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Wasn't it to show? Sorry, I'm new to the area trying to learn, and I didn't change the names on purpose, that's how I managed to do it. But I will delete these messages.

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate the multiple 4 page document into one file, then process them afterwards.

If you can safely run the command with all the files use this:

```
cpdf -merge p*.pdf AND -twoup-stack -o out.pdf
```

If you are on Linux/*BSD/macOS and need take care with filenames, use this:

```
find . -type f -name p\*.pdf -print0 | xargs -0 cpdf -merge -stdout | cpdf -twoup-stack -stdin -o out.pdf
```

The find looks for any file in the current directory starting with `p` and ending in `.pdf`.

Then pass that through `xargs -0` to safely run `cpdf` having it output to stdout.

Finally stack the file, two per page, and write to `out.pdf`.